# Slice an array index wise and push into empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have 2 arrays. one of them(`config`) decides how many elements are going to be pushed in new array(`finalData`) from existing array(`items`).

I tried to use `slice` but at the 3rd index the value is duplicated from the 2nd index. Try to run code and you'll get the idea. Here's my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-star-sphc7e?file=/src/index.js)

Desired output is that I get an array of arrays split exactly by using `config` indexes.

```js
const config = [1,2,1, 2];
const items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

const finalData = []

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if(config[i] !== undefined) { 
  finalData.push(items.slice(i, config[i] + i))
  } else {
    finalData.push([items[i]])
  }
}

console.log(finalData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output? Should it be `[ ['one'], ['two', 'three'], ['four'] ... ]` or `[ ['one'], ['two', 'three'], ['three'] ... ]` or something else? Your current code seems to output the second option

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += config[i] ?? 1) {` ??

Comment: @lucasvw yes, that's right, first one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that works, could you please spot my mistake and explain how your solution works?

Comment: When you add more than 1 item using `slice()`, you need to increment `i` by that number of items.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I tried with ```const config = [2, 3, 1];``` and it's acting weird. could you take a look at my sandbox?

Comment: Looks like my original code is a bit off. Try: `for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i += config[0] ?? 1) { finalData.push(items.slice(i, i + (config.shift() ?? 1))); }`

Comment: sorry, no luck. any idea why such behaviour. When I tried to just ```console.log(`config[i]`, config[i])``` inside loop it first print ```2``` but after that showing ```undefined```. why it's skipping 3,1 from the config?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/u84dmkhf/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah thanks it working, but If i add that ```undefined``` check condition than it won't work. wonder why ```undefined```? Anyway thanks, was a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest iterating through the config array instead of the items array

```js
const config = [1, 2, 1, 2];
const items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

const finalData = [];
let index = 0;
for (let size of config) {
  finalData.push(items.slice(index, index + size));
  index += size;
}
// then collect any remaining
while (index < items.length) {
  finalData.push([ items[index++] ]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalData));
```

If the length items can be shorter than the defined config, you may need to add some checks in to prevent empty arrays from being added to final data

Comment: thanks, could you please explain why you did ```index += size;``` instead of just ```index++```. I don't fully understand the logic behind this and it only works if we increment with ```size```.

Comment: @JeetViramgama `size` is how many elements we're adding in the current iteration and `index` is the current location in the items array. So for each iteration, we want to move our index by the number of elements we added during that iteration

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` with `splice()` to get the items from `items` array with the amount `config` provides.

If after the map, there are still items in the `items` array, use another `map()` to add those

```js
const config = [1,2,1, 2];
const items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

let finalData = config.map(n => items.splice(0, n))

if (items.length > 0) {
  finalData = [ ...finalData, ...items.map(i => [ i ]) ];
}

console.log(finalData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```json
[
  [
    "one"
  ],
  [
    "two",
    "three"
  ],
  [
    "four"
  ],
  [
    "five",
    "six"
  ],
  [
    "seven"
  ],
  [
    "eight"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through `config` array and use `.splice(0, qty)`. Since `.splice()` mutates the array, if it called on every iteration, the first parameter is 0 index by default.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const group = [1, 2, 1, 2];
const items = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight"];

// >ext< = 8 - [1 + 2 + 1 + 2] /* returns 2 */
const ext = items.length - group.reduce((sum, add) => sum + add);

// >cfg< = [1, 2, 1, 2] merge with [1, 1]
const cfg = group.concat(Array(ext).fill(1));

// >qty< = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1] returns [["one"], ["two", "three"],...]
const dat = cfg.flatMap(qty => [items.splice(0, qty)]);

console.log(dat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```